# iterating through and changing values in a form

Tags: javascript

I have a html form where the id of each element is labeled like a spreadsheet. (Sheet1_A1).  I need to iterate a column of entries and change the values.  Those values are loaded from a csv file on the server and placed into an array with javascript and jquery.  How would it be possible to change those values in the specific id's upon document load?

Comment: please provide an example of your html

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup with one of our applications. We read through the JSON array and using the property name, we use jQuery to search the DOM for the element.  Then depending on the element type, we set it's new value based on the data that the property is set.  This only happens on document load.  Then we are using the change event on each element to push any changes back to the JSON object.